# How do I track a case at USCIS without getting receipt of acknowledgement?

Tags: overstay, usa, application-status

I entered US at 24 Jun, 2016. My I-94 was valid up until 23 Dec 2016. I applied for visa extension on 5th Dec 2015 and it was received at the Dallas Lockbox on 7th Dec 2015(Can be proved by FedEx). My request for extension was until 2nd Feb 2017, but I started to apply to schools and got in. I have Form I-20 ready to file for change of status but I have not received any single communication from USCIS about my previous application.

The checks I attached with the application were cashed on 22nd March 2017, I asked the bank for a copy of the canceled check but they couldn't provide because it was done electronically. My lawyer is just waiting on receipt number from them to file for change of status which I haven't received. I have called USCIS twice in the meanwhile. I was told that immigration agent will get in touch with me about my application but to no avail. What are my current options in terms of having a lawful status in the country? I have an employer ready to file O1-A(Yes, I have that kind of profile) for me as well. But, even he can't do anything until then. Suggest some options.

Comment: Well even if the extension of status was approved, it would only be until Feb 2, which is in the past, so no matter if it is approved or denied, you will not be considered to be in status now, and so you are not eligible to file for a change of status now.

Comment: Per the comment above, unless you've left out a critical detail, you were not in status anyway and/or seem to have gotten things confused a bit.